# Journey Builder Activity cannot match config. json

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity

I occurred to the problem that I had developed a custom activity on aws EC2(OS: CENTOS 7, Enviroment: Node.js + pm2 + nginx) and had connected back to SFMC installed package.

However, when I create a new Journey in the Journey Builder, my custom activity could't display the icon and I got a "Failed to load config.json for url..." message.
[image]

But I'm sure that I can connect to config.json through my local sever.

Any further troubleshooting assistance or similar is greatly appreciated.
Thanks so much!

Comment: Is your config.json and index.html in the correct path defined for the Journey Builder Activity component in your Installed Package?

Comment: Hi @Macca , thanks for your advice. My app was deployed reference the gitHub documentation [Custom Activities - Desk.com API](https://github.com/sfmc-developer-advocates/custom-activity-deskapi-node). I put my config.json and index.html file in the path /public/ixn/activities/myApp/ and defined Journey Builder Activity component with https://myUrl/ixn/activities/myApp.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I asked the same question on the [Trailblazer Community](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/0D54S000006AJHs).
I found that I missed the config.js file in my file structure.
Hope that It's helpful for someone having similar questions.